# Jquery get selected value and change css

Tags: jquery, forms, onchange

I have a form drop down list. When I change the value in the drop down, I want to hide a css element.

**The HTML**

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <select name="category" id="category>
    <option value="0">Foo</option>
    <option value="1">Bar</option>
    <option value="2">Test</option>
    </select>
```

The jQuery

```
$("#category").change(function () {
$('tr.foobar').css("display","none");
});
```

I only get "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function" in the console log. I've made this work before, but I can't understand what the problem is here?

Comment: That error does not appear to have anything to do with the code you have posted.

Comment: @Stitchy also with the fact you are missing the last " on `id="category"` the change event would never have been bound

Comment: i think @mayank has answered it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery hide().

```
$("#category").change(function () {
        $('tr.foobar').hide()
});
```

see below link:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a double quote after select id

```
<select name="category" id="category">
```

Fixing this makes the code go through fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/mayank_agarwal/JEj84/

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery `.hide()` with different attributes:

```
$("#category").change(function () {
$( "tr.footbar" ).hide( "slow" );
//$( "tr.footbar" ).hide( "fast" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the double quote on id="category".